# Angular render view after parameter changed in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh

***High level***
I header view and a main view in my angular application. I want the header to have a "back" button that is show/hidden based on the page I'm on.

***What I did***
app.js (snippet)

```
app.factory('globalServices', function() {
    return {
        showBack : false,
        back: function() {
            window.history.back();
        }
    };
});
```

header.html (snippet)

```
<a class="button-prev" ng-click="back()" ng-show="showBackButton">
    Back
</a>
```

headerCtrl.js (snippet)

```
$scope.showBackButton = globalServices.showBack;
$scope.back = function() {
    globalServices.back();
};
```

subPageCtrl.js (snippet)

```
globalServices.showBack = true;
```

***Problem***
The button viability isn't refreshed after the value is changed. I only see the value changed after I move one more page.

Is there a way to fix it?

I'm also open for a different approach.

***Edit***
Trying to call `$scope.$apply();` also failed with error `$digest already in progress` because I'm changing this value as part of the constructor of subPageCtrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.showBackButton = globalServices.showBack;
```

only set's showBackButton to globalServices.showBack once (during controller initialization).  Future changes to globalServices.showBack aren't propagated to the $scope.showBackButton, which is the value that your UI is bound to.

You have two options:

1)

```
$scope.$watch('globalServices.showBack', function(){
    $scope.showBackButton = globalServices.showBack;
}
```

This option will watch globalServices.showBack for changes, and then set $scope.showBackButton to match on any change.

or

2)

```
$scope.globalServices = globalServices;

<a class="button-prev" ng-click="globalServices.back()" ng-show="globalServices.showBackButton">
    Back
</a>
```

This option exposes globalServices directly to your UI.  This is how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when booleans are passed, they are assigned by value (they are a by value type) so when you are doing `$scope.showBackButton = globalServices.showBack;` it is assigning the value of `$scope.showBackButton` to the value of `globalServices.showBack` so if you change the value of `globalServices.showBack` it won't change the value of `$scope.showBackButton`.

To fix this you should used an object which is assigned by reference:

```
app.factory('globalServices', function() {
    return {
        showButtonDetails: {
            showBack : false
        },
        back: function() {
            window.history.back();
        }
    };
});

<a class="button-prev" ng-click="back()" ng-show="showButtonDetails.showBack">
    Back
</a>

$scope.showButtonDetails = globalServices.showButtonDetails;
$scope.back = function() {
    globalServices.back();
};

globalServices.showButtonDetails.showBack = true;
```